# Проблема с функцией GetAsyncKeyState()

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня есть меню, которое управляется стрелками и на нажатие `Enter` переходит по нужному пункту. Проблема в том, что все нажатия `Enter` сохраняются в буфера ввода.
Допустим, после перехода по выбранному пункту пользователем нужно ввести какое либо значение, и из-за сохранения "прошлого" `Enter'a` у меня просто автоматически вводиться значение `'\n'`.
Как это можно пофиксить?

Код:

```
    char check(void) { // Обработка нажатий клавиш
        while (true) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(80));
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) == -32767)
                return VK_UP;
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) == -32767)
                return VK_DOWN;
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) == -32767)
                return VK_RETURN;
        }
    };



    while (true) // Обработка клавиш
                switch (check()) {
                case VK_UP:
                    // Up
                    if (presentItem != 0) {
                        presentItem--;
                        system("cls");
                        show(entries, 2, presentItem);
                    }
                    break;
                case VK_DOWN:
                    // Down
                    if (presentItem != 1) {
                        presentItem++;
                        system("cls");
                        show(entries, 2, presentItem);
                    }
                    break;
                case VK_RETURN:
                    if (presentItem == 0) {
                        createList();
                        system("cls");
                        firstMenu();
                    }
                    else {
                        createList();
                        loadList();
                        system("cls");
                        firstMenu();
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

    void loadList() {
        system("cls");

        std::string nameFile;

        std::cout << "File: "; // Error - Автоматический ввод '\n'
        std::cin >> nameFile;
  ...
  }
```

Comment: в цикле обработчика сообщений следует "поглощать" обработанные сообщения. Как я понимаю ситуация следующая, пользователь ходит по меню, жмёт Ввод, вы открываете какую-то форму с полем ввода и этот же Ввод прилетает туда. Поскольку в вопросе нифига не видно как там у вас организован user-input и очереди сообщений, то больше помочь ничем не могу

Comment: залейте куда-нибудь полный код проекта, как я понимаю у вас это всё в консоли и еще есть какие-то потоки, которые судя по всему опрашивают клавиатуру. Но скорее всего переделывать придется много)

Comment: А как я их поглотить то могу?

Comment: std::cin.clear(); возможно вот сюда вставить void loadList()  перед вводом

Comment: Я пробовал так сделать, все тщетно...
Вот сам .cpp файл - http://rgho.st/8Hgqjsy7F

Comment: Только там не на Enter сделано, а на Y. Но суть одна и та же

Comment: Попробуйте при вызове `GetAsyncKeyState` возвращаемое значение проверять на наличие установленного младшего бита (`GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 1`). [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать

```
FlushConsoleInputBuffer( GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE ) );
```

Вызывать следует перед запросом входного буфера `std::cin >>`
Например я проверял на функции:

```
void addEntry() {
    listStudents* newStudent = new listStudents;
    system("cls");

    FlushConsoleInputBuffer( GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE ) );
    std::cout << "ФИО: "; // Теперь y уже не появляется
    std::cin >> newStudent->student.name;
...
```

P.S. перед каждым `std::cin >>` вызывать нет нужды, достаточно вызывать перед началом блока ввода, ну т.е. 1 раз на функцию addEntry(). Вызовы `std::cin.ignore(...)` лучше удалить, т.к. это не совсем то, что надо и может давать не совсем те эффекты, которые нужны.